# SDK Facebook app - allow to use the app only on FB, not on my website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am newbie in creating apps for Facebook and I would like to ask you about a few things.

I created my first app, in the settings I set up the `domain URL`, `canvas URL`, etc... when I load the app via `apps.facebook.com/my_app_name` the app is working, *but* also when I visit the page via the `canvas URL` I configured.

Is there any way to only allow access to the app only when loaded inside the Facebook chrome?

Also, in the app that I made are some links, buttons, etc. and when you hover over them with the mouse you can see my own domain in the status bar below. Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your page is called from within Facebook it receives a `signed_request` via `$_POST`. You can show the page based on that, or perhaps redirect to `apps.facebook.com/yourapp` instead.

See also: [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

As for the links that show in the status bar, you need to rewrite those links to point to `apps.facebook.com/yourapp/somepage`. When you do that, the link target should be set to `_top`.

Alternatively, you could do things like this:

```
<a href="#" data-url="/mypage?id=123" class="hidden-url">click me</a>
```

And then with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.hidden-url').on('click', function(evt) {
        location = $(this).data('url');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've tried to update the links: `$url = 'http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/'; echo '<a href="'.$url.'index.php?some_param=123">text</a>';` - but when I try rewrite links this way, so nothing happen - also I've tried to `print_r($_GET)`, but I got just an empty array... the `echo '<a href="index.php?some_param=123">text</a>'` works well, but there is displayed URL to my website...

Comment: Jack: I solved it this way: `echo '<a href="'.$url.'index.php?some_param=123" target="_parent">text</a>'`. But, I still hesitate if this solution is the best. Also, what bothers me is, that all parameters are visible in the URL - this I will probably hide with using AJAX.

Comment: I'm trying to make work your new code, but I'm not very successful. The problem is, that when I move cursor to link, in the status bar is displayed `my-website.com/#` and when I click on this link, so nothing happen... I attempted to add into JS function `window.location = location;` before `return false;`, but it didn't help me.

Comment: @user984621 you need to have jQuery loaded though. And yes, it still shows your domain, but then again if you have something to hide perhaps you have something else to fix first :)